# Custom ListView ItemClick stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I had a custom `ListView` that contained

1. Business details
2. Navigation button
3. Call button

All of them were clickeble and had onClick method.

---

Today, I changed my buttons to imageButtons and my business details do nothing when I click on them.

Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/place_cell_bg" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bussiness_item_image"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_telphone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_buttons_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_call_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="@string/call_button_text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_nav_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="@string/nav_button_text" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bussiness_item_text_layout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bussiness_item_buttons_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_food_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bussiness_item_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the code where you assign the listeners.

Comment: does imageview take focus when you click on listitem